# type error of parsing of json data while creating a user login using flutter and php

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a user login using flutter and backend in php. But while pursing the json data when login is valid flutter shows error: **"type '_OneByteString' is not a subtype of type int"**. But strangly when wrong email or password given no error appears and the Snackbar is displayed but the progressIndicator keeps showing indefinitely. I can't understand the problem since in both cases String is returned as Status. Please help me. I am stuck here for 2 days. Here's my flutter code:

```
 Future<Login> userLogin(String email, String password) async {
 Map<String, dynamic> map = {'email': email, 'password': password};

  final http.Response response = await http.post(
  'my php page',
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(map),
);

 if (response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 200) {
   return Login.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
 } else {
   throw Exception('Failed to login.');
 }
}

 class Login {
  final int usrid;
  //final String usrname;
  final String status;

  Login({this.usrid, this.status});

  factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Login(usrid: json['usrid'], status: json['type']);
 }
 }

 class TextControl extends StatefulWidget {
   TextControl({Key key}) : super(key: key);
   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return _TextControl();
  }
 }

 class _TextControl extends State<TextControl> {
   final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
   final TextEditingController _controller2 = TextEditingController();

 @override
 void dispose() {
  // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
  _controller.dispose();
  _controller2.dispose();
  super.dispose();
 }

Future<Login> _futureLogin;
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: (_futureLogin == null)
      ? Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty || !value.isValidEmail()) {
                  return 'Please enter valid email.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller2,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter password.';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.purple[400],
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    setState(() {
                      _futureLogin =
                          userLogin(_controller.text, _controller2.text);
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      : FutureBuilder<Login>(
          future: _futureLogin,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              //return Text(snapshot.data.usrname);
              if (snapshot.data.status == '1') {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TextInput()),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.data.status == '2') {
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(content: Text('Invalid login credentials.')));
              }
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ),
    );
   }
  }
```

I returned String '1' for valid login and String '2' for invalid login. So why the error occurrs only for valid login? And for invalid login the message 'Invalid credentials' is showing but the ProgressIndicator does not stop. How can I stop this and show login screen? Please help me regarding the 2 issues. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And when login is valid user id is returned in json['usrid'] which is int and for invalid login json['usrid'] is 0 which is also int. That's because I used final int usrid; in class Login.

Comment: The `CircularProgressIndicator` doesn't go away because you don't return anything when `snapshot.data.status = '2'`, so it defaults to returning the indicator again.

Comment: And as far as the error for the successful login, I suspect that the return value for `json['usrId']` is not actually an int as you believe but is actually a string. Print the response JSON string to make sure of what you are actually receiving from the server.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So if I return null for snapshot.data.status = '2' will it work? Because for invalid login there is nothing to return, just needs to showing the Snackbar with the message.

Comment: You can't return null, since a builder function has to return something. If you don't want to return anything, then the builder function is the wrong place for that code.

Comment: Regarding your second answer, I am returing user id for valid login which is int, But the json for it is $status['usrid'] = $userid. Since the key 'usrid' is string, that's why the error is occurring?

Comment: Ok..so what I should return for invalid login? I want the Snackbar will show with the mesage and the login form will be displayed for re-entering the credentials.

Comment: That's not "the json for it", that's the value representation on the PHP side. I'm telling you to check the raw JSON response that you are actually getting on the Flutter side from the http request.

Comment: It's not my app, I can't tell you what to return. You just have to return something. Or get this code out of the build function entirely.

Comment: Do `print(response.body);` and paste the output here.

Comment: Sorry, by print(response.body); the loader continues to move and no data comes. I don't have device directly connnected to my code. So I had to build the apk and install into the phone to see the changes. Perhaps that's why nothing appeared.

Comment: Changing final int usrid; to final String usrid; the error occurred by valid login is solved. But for invalid login for snapshot.data.status == '2', flutter shows error: **"type '_Smi' is not a subtype of type 'String'"**. What is type '_Smi'? The json['type'] is String for both valid login and invalid login. So why invalid login is showing error and valid login works perfectly? I have no clue!! Please help!

Comment: I believe that `_OneByteString` and `_Smi` are internal types for the JSON parser representing (in a nutshell) a string value and an integer value, respectively. What this is telling me is that your PHP backend probably has a bug and is returning an `int` for the user ID on an unsuccessful login and a `String` for the user ID on a successful login. You will need to track down and fix that bug in order for your Flutter side to work properly.

Comment: Thanks. It is fixed by changing the json format in php. But the form goes way after showing the error message. Is it for I am using super.dispose()?